# Animation in splash screen android doesn't work properly

Tags: android, animation, startup, splash-screen

i have a transition on my slashscreen but sometimes animation starts, others not.
I can't understand how to solve this, here the splash activity with the animation of a textview. The strange thing is that sometimes it works correctly, in particular on emulator it works more times than on device.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    title1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);        
    animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.long_slide_left);

    title1.startAnimation(animation1);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this, mainActivity.class);

            SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(intent);               

            SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();

            // transition from splash to main menu
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activityfadein,
                    R.anim.activityfadeout);

        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Handler, Try this simple Thread.

```
Thread splash=new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {


                        sleep(3000);



                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    finish();
                    Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
        splash.start();
```

Comment: The problemm persist...i've tried moving "title1.startAnimation(animation1);" in onResume event, but sometimes if i start repetitively happens that the animation doesn't start.